# Update/refresh Table in QGIS-Layout

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, print-composer, table

I have two tables in my layout. One is a Attribute table (of a polygon layer) the other one a table which shows the Sum of the first table multiply by 2.

[image: Upper Table is a Attribute Table, Table below a "simple" table]

While the attribute table is updated when make changes to the polygons the table doesnt update at all and there is not even a refresh button (or something else)

To update this table i have to edit the table (in Item Properties) > Open the expression builder > and click ok

[image: Table designer with expressions]

...and I have to do this for every cell.

Is there an easier way to "update" this table?